# How to consume python machine learning libraries like Numpy, Scipy, Pandas, Tensorflow through Node JS

Tags: python, node.js, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am having ML code written in Python. I want to use child_process in Node JS and leverage Python's Machine Learning capabilities for predictions. I used **NUMPY, Pandas, Tensorflow, Scipy** python libraries. My question is, if I want to run this using NODE, where and how I will load python libraries.